# RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! when resuming training in LLMs

Tags: python, pytorch, large-language-model

I'm trying to do the inference of `flan-T5` model I got this error and don't know where to put `.cuda()`

```
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0!...
```

```
index = 200
dialogue = dataset['test'][index]['req_aDefinition']
baseline_human_summary = dataset['test'][index]['test Action']

prompt = f"""
Write the test action for this requirement definition.

{dialogue}

test Action:
"""
input_ids = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").input_ids

original_model_outputs = original_model.generate(input_ids=input_ids, generation_config=GenerationConfig(max_new_tokens=2000, num_beams=1))
original_model_text_output = tokenizer.decode(original_model_outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)



peft_model_outputs = peft_model.generate(input_ids=input_ids, generation_config=GenerationConfig(max_new_tokens=2000, num_beams=1))
peft_model_text_output = tokenizer.decode(peft_model_outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

print(dash_line)
print(f'BASELINE HUMAN TEST ACTION:\n{human_baseline_summary}')
print(dash_line)
print(f'ORIGINAL MODEL:\n{original_model_text_output}')

print(dash_line)
print(f'PEFT MODEL: {peft_model_text_output}')`
```